# Change tf.dataset source at runtime in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have two tf.datasets, one for validation and one for training.

Every now and again I want to switch the data source so that I can run the validation and check some accuracy measure on it.

[This blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-dataset-in-tensorflow-c758ef9e4428) suggests to use placeholders and feed normal numpy arrays to it. But this would defeat the entire efficiency purpose;
As the [tf.data API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data#_tf_data_API) api guide says:

> Warning: "Feeding" is the least efficient way to feed data into a TensorFlow program and should only be used for small experiments and debugging.

So, here is a conceptual example of what I want to achieve:

```
# Load the datasets from tfrecord files:
val_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset([val_recordfile])
train_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset([train_recordfile])

##  Batch size end shuffeling etc. here  ##

iterator_tr = train_dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
iterator_val = val_dataset.make_initializable_iterator()

###############################################
##  This is the magic:                       ##
it_op=tf.iterator_placeholder()
##  tf.iterator_placeholder does not exist!  ##
##  and demonstrates my needs                ##
###############################################
X, Y = it_op.get_next()
predictions=model(X)
train_op=train_and_minimize(X,Y)
acc_op=get_accuracy(Y,predictions)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Initialize iterator here
    accuracy_tr,_=sess.run([acc_op,train_op], feed_dict={it_op: iterator_tr})
    accuracy_val=sess.run(acc_op, feed_dict={it_op: iterator_val})
```

It does *not* of course has to be done in this exact way!

I'd prefer a pytonic/ideomatic tensorflow way, but any way that does not require feeding raw data is great for me!

Comment: If I got you right, you don't need to use feed_dict. Just pass X, Y to any function

Comment: I do not think you got me right. I did figure it out. I think. I'll update here when It's all as smooth as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, my suggestion wasn't that far off of what worked. It was actually presented in [the Tensorflow's guide on datasets](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets):

```
# Load the datasets in some form of tf.Dataset
tr_dataset=get_dataset(TRAINING)
val_dataset=get_dataset(VALIDATION)
# batching etc..
train_iterator = tr_dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
val_iterator = val_dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
# Make iterator handle that takes a string identifier
iterator_handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[])
iterator=tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(iterator_handle, train_iterator.output_types,output_shapes=train_iterator.output_shapes)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Create string handlers for the iterators
    train_iterator_handle = sess.run(train_iterator.string_handle())
    val_iterator_handle = sess.run(val_iterator.string_handle())
    # Now initialize iterators
    sess.run(train_iterator.initializer, feed_dict={iterator_handle: train_iterator_handle})
    sess.run(val_iterator.initializer, feed_dict={iterator_handle: val_iterator_handle})
```